# onclick "Continue" in Cart.php, i need to display a value "$tot" from ajax_cart.php in Cart.php

Tags: php, ajax, onclick

Cart.php :
ajax code calling ajax_cart from Cart.php  to display value for total amount calculation. On clicking Continue i need to get value displayed in same page..

```
ajax code

function gettotal(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax_cart_total.php',
                data: {action: 'call'},
                success: function(html){
                    alert html;
                }
                });
        }


html
*****
<a class="btn btn-default check_out" href="" onClick="gettotal()">Continue</a>
<li>Total <span id="disp2"></span></li> // value from ajax_cart should be displayed here..
```

ajax_cart.php :
required values are taken from table and calculated to get total amount

```
<?php
@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("onlineshopping");
session_start();
$s=$_SESSION['USER']['ID'];
if($_POST['action']=='call'){
$c=mysql_query("select * from totcalcu where USER_ID='$s'");
$cr=mysql_fetch_array($c);
$subt=$cr['SUBTOTAL'];
$tax=$cr['TAX'];
$ship=$cr['SHIPPING_COST'];
$tot=$subt+$tax+$ship; // calculation of total done
    ?>
<span id="disp2"><?php echo $tot; ?></span>
<?php 
$ins=mysql_query("update totcalcu set TOTAL='$tot' where USER_ID='$s'");
}
?>
```

i cannot change html code..please do help